# A Function that Returns 2 Arrays (Passing By Reference)

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to do a function in c++ that returns 2 arrays by passing them from reference.
I have no idea and it seems noone also has.
Would you be so kind to write an exemple for me?
I thaught to do

```
int *vettore=new int[5];
return vettore
```

buy it only returns one.
Tnx in advance.

Comment: Yep, i have no idea how toreturn the second one. This is how i usally make an array return. Buyt i can do only with one.

Comment: Please show full code and ask clearly what you want to do

Comment: Return a `pair` of pointer to the two arrays. See here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/

Comment: *"it seems noone also has"* - if your teacher doesn't know how to do this then how are they planning to grade you on it?

Comment: Guys. I really don't have a full code because I assisted an exam today and the teacher asked to make a function that returns two arrays by passing something from reference. She clearly can't do that herself and can't explain also to the others one. So we are in ttly shit lol. I am sorry to can't give you further explaination.

Comment: @AsimRaja they are not passed by reference. There is an array to pointer decay happening, but no references involved whatsoever unless you explicitly make it a reference.

Comment: She kept like screaming "you have to pass it by reference" without explaining and probably she doesn't know how what and where since i attended all her course and she never told us something like this

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: I know it could be way simpler but she wouldn't let us

Comment: I'm only guessing here, but could the teacher mean that you have to pass two *pointers* by reference? Like e.g. `int*& array1`? It's not the same as passing an *array* by reference (which is possible but kind of useless).

Comment: She asked to write "a function that returns two different arrays". Obsly since noone has told us how to do it, the guy in exam didn't accomplish it and she went like totally crazy screaming "by reference by reference" without explaining nothing else.

Comment: Returning 2 arrays *could* be done via a return value of `std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>>` or similar variations, but that doesn't seem to be what your teacher is after. You need to ask for clarification, as it is unclear what you are supposed to do (or how you are supposed to do it)

Comment: What is "returns 2 arrays by passing them from reference" anyway? It makes no sense. "return by passing" is contradictory. Parameters cannot be "passed *from* reference".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's forget about arrays for a second, because that is another bag of problems. Let's concentrate on returning two simple types, e.g. returning two integers.

Obviously this won't work (because... not python):

```
int, int foo()
{
   int a = ...
   int b = ...

   return a, b;
}
```

So what options are you left with if you want to *return* multiple values in C++?

#### Option 1. Return a class

You can "bundle" your values in a class, either create a new class for them if that makes sense, or simply use `std::pair` or `std::tuple`:

```
std::pair<int, int> foo()
{
   int a = ...;
   int b = ...;

   return {a, b}
}
```

#### Option 2. Use "out" parameters.

You can pass parameters by reference, thus being able to modify from within the function objects from outside. E.g.:

```
void foo(int& a, int& b)
{
   a = ...;
   b = ...;
}
```

I think this is what you teacher meant by "pass by reference".

#### Ok, what about arrays?

This is tricky to answer because it is not clear what you mean by `arrays` and some of the meanings are discouraged.

I will start from the most recommended, to what is considered bad practice and even wrong:

#### `std::vector`

The defacto type for representing arrays in C++ should always be `std::vector`. Thus your requirement of returning by reference could mean:

```
void foo(std::vector<int>& v1, std::vector<int&>& v2);
```

#### `std::array`

Alternately if the size of the array is known at compile time:

```
void foo(std::array<int, 24>& a1, std::array<int, 24>& a2);
```

#### C pointers

Ok, now we are in the discouraged territory. **Don't do this**, unless to appease an unreasonable teacher or curriculum:

```
void foo(int* &v1, int* &v2)
{
   v1 = new int[11];
   v2 = new int[24];
   ...
}
```

#### C arrays

```
void foo(int (&a)[11], int (&a2)[24]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
return std::make_pair(array1,array2);
```

You'll need to `#include <utility>`

To access the arrays use pair.first or pair.second

example:

```
#include <utility>  //std::pair
#include <iostream> //std::cout 
std::pair<int*,int*> returnpair(){ 
    int arr1[3] = {1,2,3};
    int arr2[3] = {4,5,6};
    return std::make_pair(arr1,arr2);
 } 
int main(){ 
    std::pair<int*,int*> pair= returnpair();
    std::cout<<pair.first[1]; //access 2nd member of arr1
}
```

Output:

```
2
```

Reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by returning a struct node pointer which is acceptable in C/C++.

Following is the sample code of node :

```
 struct node {
   int a[100];
   int b[100];
};
```

Coming to the function :

```
struct node* fun() {
      struct node* ptr;  
     // write your code
     return ptr;
}
```

In main : you can access the arrays as follows :

```
  struct node* ptr=fun();
  ptr->a  // is the first array
  ptr->b  // is the second array
```

Hope it helps